# is there an OP_RETURN or MEMO field in Tezos transactions?

Tags: transactions

I'm looking for a way to store information (few bytes) in a Tezos transaction, on BTC I'm using OP_RETURN field but is there a similar field in Tezos transactions ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you're trying to do. Are you sending these transactions to anyone? To a specific address?

In the most general case, you could take advantage of the fact that Tezos transactions are batches by default. Whenever you create a transaction, you would add another transaction to the operation that passes a bit of information to a smart-contract. The smart-contract itself need not do anything with that information, it can just drop it and return, for example:

```
parameter bytes;
storage unit;
code {CDR; NIL operation; PAIR};
```

Support for batch operations is currently lacking in the command-line interface, but here's a blog post explaining how you can create them with RPC calls

https://medium.com/@bakenrolls/sending-multiple-transactions-in-one-batch-using-tezos-rpc-6cab3a21f254

---

This will do the job but it wouldn't be a bad idea to add native support for a memo field in transactions in future protocol versions.

Comment: I'm trying to send these transactions to a specific address in order to keep a trace of the memo content. Currently I'm evaluating two possibilities, either adding this memo in a transaction or record it into a dedicated smart contract

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's a good idea not to record any data on the chain unless the validity of a future transaction will depend on that data. If all you need is to track that it happened, you may just as well pass that data as a parameter to your transactions but not store it.

Comment: indeed, this is the reason why I'm looking for the best way to pass data as parameter ;-)